# Convertir de double a varchar

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo un InnerJoin de tres tablas, dentro de ese Inner necesito cambiar el tipo de dato de la columna completa de double a varchar, no lo puedo hacer en la base de datos ya que solo tengo acceso a ella en modo consulta y estoy conectado mediante SQLSeveloper entonces aqui genero yo mis consultas para ser usadas en otras aplicaciones.

Son alrededor de 5 campos los que necesito cambiar, un ejemplo:

```
TABLA1.DIAMETER_AREA as "DIAMETER",--> 'Como lo cambio de double a varchar

SELECT TABLA1, CAST(DIAMETER_AREA as varchar(8)) DIAMETER_AREA FROM TABLA1 ORDER BY DIAMETER_AREA DESC
```

Pero no me esta corriendo la consulta, alguien me puede ayudar que es lo que tengo mal?

Comment: ¿Algún mensaje de error o simplemente no regresa resultados? Veo que tu select puede tener un error, debería quedar así.. SELECT CAST(DIAMETER_AREA as varchar(8)) DIAMETER_AREA FROM TABLA1 ORDER BY DIAMETER_AREA DESC (le eliminé el nombre TABLA1 que tenía después del SELECT).

Comment: Ya me correo el CAST con lo que quitaste, pero como la meto en todo el INNER JOIN, solo corri esa parte aparte en una SELECT

FROM ((Y55B INNER JOIN W55A ON (Y55B.NBR  = W55A.NBR ) AND (Y55B.PLANT_ID = W55A.PLANT_ID)) 
INNER JOIN T53D ON (W55A.VER= T53D.VER) AND (W55A.FAM= T53D.FAM) AND (W55A.NBR  = T53D.NBR ) AND (W55A.PLANT_ID = T53D.PLANT_ID))

Comment: @Javier Reséndiz
Se me olvido agregar

Comment: Puse como respuesta lo comentado, ya que con eso se responde la consulta de la conversión. No me queda claro si hay una duda adicional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es tanto un problema de la conversión, sino de la sintaxis del select. Se elimina el nombre de la tabla al inicio y queda del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT CAST(DIAMETER_AREA as varchar(8)) DIAMETER_AREA FROM TABLA1 ORDER BY DIAMETER_AREA DESC
```

Con eso la conversión ya no da error.

Comment: Si la solución esta dada pero lo que trato de mencionar es como puedo meter esa solución dentro de mi INNER JOIN

Comment: Intento añadir la solución dada al INNER pero aun no me queda en mi consulta.

Comment: Ok. Me parece que sería conveniente crear otra pregunta para mejor seguimiento. Es conveniente incluir información adicional como mensajes de error, estructura de tablas, etc.